# found errors in your .gitlab-ci.yml: local file does not have project

Tags: gitlab, include, gitlab-ci

In my GitLab project I specify my CI configuration file at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Nakama-Partnering-Services/project-scaffolding/main/.gitlab-ci.yml.

If I try to use `includes: environments.yml` it fails with:

> local file environments.yml does not have project!

Even if such yml file exist in my GitLab project: https://gitlab.com/jdkgabri/project-scaffolding (althoug I removed in the latest commits)

My aim is to separate the `.dest-envs` config in line 43 to specify the different values at project level, by having an `environments.yml` in the project with this config, including always the file with that name, so that I can mantain a single .gitlab-ci.yml in the public remote repo, to be used in a generic way across different GitLab projects that may require different environments (see TODO in line 81).

How can I make includes local work with a remote gitlab-ci.yml?

[image]

[image]

Comment: See if this helps https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-vscode-extension/-/issues/213

Comment: This was the first link I came across when googling. It does not help much, it is a different thing that, in fact, was fixed already.

Comment: @Stephan unfortunately not. I gave up on that.

Comment: @GabrielSerranoSalas I found if you shift to the full raw url of the file you want to include, it'll bypass this issue. I haven't found the root cause either.